# SharePoint Context and Caml query is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, csom

Here is  my code..

```
var  CmalQuery="";
var fieldName="";
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#btnSearch').on('click', function () {
        txtValue = $('#txtSearch').val();
         fn();
    });
     $('#btnList').on('click', function () {
        fn1();
    });
     $('select').on('change', function () {
       ListName = this.value;
       retrieveFieldsOfListView(ListName);
       txtValue = $('#txtSearch').val();
         // or $(this).val()
    });    
    });



function fn() {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var user = context.get_web().get_currentUser();
    //Get the Announcements list. Alter this code to match the name of your list  
    var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(ListName);
    //Create a new CAML query  
    var caml = new SP.CamlQuery();
    //Create the CAML that will return only items with the titles that contains with 'txtValue' 
   // var CmalQuery = "<View><Query><Where><Or>";
   // CmalQuery += "<Contains><FieldRef Name='EmpName' /><Value Type='Text'>" + txtValue + "</Value></Contains>";
   // CmalQuery += "<Contains><FieldRef Name='Company' /><Value Type='Text'>" + txtValue + "</Value></Contains>";
   // CmalQuery += "</Or></Where></Query></View>"
    caml.set_viewXml(CmalQuery);
    //Specify the query and load the list oject  
   var returnedItems = list.getItems(caml);
    context.load(returnedItems);
    //Run the query asynchronously, passing the functions to call when a response arrives  
    context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySuccess, onQueryFail);
    function onQuerySuccess(sender, args) {
        //Get an enumerator for the items in the list  
        var enumerator = returnedItems.getEnumerator();
        //Formulate HTML from the list items  
        var markup = 'Items in the Employee Details list that contains with ' + '"' + txtValue + '"' + ': <br><br><table class="table table-striped">';
               //Loop through all the items  
        while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
            var listItem = enumerator.get_current();
            markup += '<tr><td>' + listItem.get_item(fieldName).get_lookupValue() + '</td></tr>';
           // markup += '<td>' + listItem.get_item('JobTitle') + '</td>';
          //  markup += '<td> ' + listItem.get_item('Title') + '</td> ';
          //  markup += '<td>' + listItem.get_item('ManagerName').get_lookupValue() + '</td></tr>';
            //Display the formulated HTML in the displayDiv element  
        }
        markup += '</table>'
        $('#resultsDiv').html(markup);
    }
    function onQueryFail(sender, args) {//Formulate HTML to display details of the error  
        var markup = '<p>The request failed: <br>';
        markup += 'Message: ' + args.get_message() + '<br>';
        //Display the details  
        $('#resultsDiv').html(markup);
    }


}
function fn1() {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var user = context.get_web().get_currentUser();
    var oWebsite = context.get_web();
    this.collList = oWebsite.get_lists();
    context.load(collList);

    context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded,onQueryFailed);
    function onQuerySucceeded() {
        var listInfo = '<table class="table table-striped"><tr>';
        var listEnumerator = collList.getEnumerator();

        while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();

            listInfo += '<tr><td>Title: ' + oList.get_title() + '</td></tr>';

           $("#ddlTitles").append($("<option></option>").html(oList.get_title()));
        }
        listInfo +='</tr></table>'
         $('#resultsDiv').html(listInfo);



    }
    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
            '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
}

function retrieveFieldsOfListView(ListName) {

    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(ListName);
    var view = list.get_views().getByTitle('All Items');
    var listFields = view.get_viewFields();
    context.load(listFields);
    context.executeQueryAsync(printFieldNames, onError);


    function printFieldNames() {
        var e = listFields.getEnumerator();
      CmalQuery += "<View><Query><Where><Contains><Or>";
        while (e.moveNext()) {
            fieldName = e.get_current();

            CmalQuery += "<FieldRef Name='"+fieldName+"' /><Value Type='Text'>" + txtValue + "</Value>";

            console.log(fieldName);

        }
          CmalQuery += "</Or></Contains></Where></Query></View>";
    }

    function onError(sender, args) {
        console.log(args.get_message());
    }
    }
```

But while calling fn Function query is failing..

Comment: what is the error you are getting? Check debugger tool (F12)

Answer (score 2):

Here this code will work only in case of 2 fields available in your list. 
It will not work for more or less than 2 fields.

**Reason:**

CAML you are formatting is wrong.

While building a CAML query it should be always in pair of 2 conditions

```
CmalQuery += "<View><Query><Where><Contains><Or>";
        while (e.moveNext()) {
            fieldName = e.get_current();

            CmalQuery += "<FieldRef Name='"+fieldName+"' /><Value Type='Text'>" + txtValue + "</Value>";

            console.log(fieldName);

        }
          CmalQuery += "</Or></Contains></Where></Query></View>";
```

your this block will not generate a pair of condition. It will generate something like this:

```
<View><Query><Where><Contains>
<Or>
  <FieldRef Name='fieldName1' /><Value Type='Text'>txtValue1</Value>
  <FieldRef Name='fieldName2' /><Value Type='Text'>txtValue2</Value>
  <FieldRef Name='fieldName3' /><Value Type='Text'>txtValue3</Value>
</Or>
</Contains></Where></Query></View>
```

Ideally it should be something like this:

```
<View><Query><Where><Contains>
  <Or>
    <Or>
      <FieldRef Name='fieldName1' /><Value Type='Text'>txtValue1</Value>
      <FieldRef Name='fieldName2' /><Value Type='Text'>txtValue2</Value>
    </Or>
    <FieldRef Name='fieldName3' /><Value Type='Text'>txtValue3</Value>
  </Or>
 </Contains></Where></Query></View>
```

**How To Write Dynamic CAML :**

While writing CAML query, you must understand the architecture how it works.

It is pretty simple. You just have to do logical `AND`/`OR` operators.

Any operator must have 2 conditions to combine and test.

**SCENARIO 1 :** This is 1 Operator use with 2 conditions

```
 <Or>
      <Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>(3) TestStatus3</Value></Eq>
       <Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>(2) TestStatus2</Value></Eq>              
 </Or>
```

**SCENARIO 2 :** This is 2 Operators use with 2 conditions 
From scenario 1 we got operator now along with that we will add another  operator.

```
<And>
    <Or>
      <Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>(3) TestStatus3</Value></Eq>
       <Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>(2) TestStatus2</Value></Eq>              
    </Or>
    <Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>(1) TestStatus1</Value></Eq>                  
</And>
```

Here if you notice, `<OR>` is having two conditions inside it. and that makes 1 condition for outer `<And>`, so we added another condition block parallel to `<OR>` operator. Hence 2 conditions are available for `<AND>`.

Likewise you can build ***n*** number of nested conditions.

PS: If you have only 1 condition, it will not require any operator.

Comment: Thanku you soo much

Comment: most welcome :)

Comment: you can accept if worked for you. will be helpful for others

Answer (score 1):

Remove `'` from the query and try like this

```
CmalQuery += "<FieldRef Name="+fieldName+" /><Value Type=Text>" + txtValue + "</Value>";
```

Maybe this will work.

Comment: this will not work, '  is must

Comment: I have not tested the above code.
But in my case it works.

Comment: values need quotes