# CAML Query to get approved items and items submitted before today is failing

Tags: caml

I do not have a CAML Builder installed so just wanted to freehand this code. However I find that it is failing.

```
<View>
<Query>
    <Where>
        <And>
            <Leq>
            <FieldRef Name=\'StartDate\' />
            <Value Type=\'DateTime\'><Today />
            </Value>
            </Leq>
        </And>
        <And>
            <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="_ModerationStatus" />
            <Value Type="ModStat">0</Value>
            </Eq>
        </And>
    </Where>
<OrderBy>
<FieldRef Name=\'StartDate\' Ascending=\'FALSE\'/>
</OrderBy>
</Query>
<RowLimit>1</RowLimit>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<View>
<Query>
    <Where>
        <And>
            <Leq>
               <FieldRef Name=\'StartDate\' />
               <Value Type=\'DateTime\'><Today />
               </Value>
            </Leq>          
            <Eq>
               <FieldRef Name="_ModerationStatus" />
               <Value Type="ModStat">0</Value>
            </Eq>
        </And>
    </Where>
<OrderBy>
<FieldRef Name=\'StartDate\' Ascending=\'FALSE\'/>
</OrderBy>
</Query>
<RowLimit>1</RowLimit>
```

Nesting of And condition was wrong.

Check [my answer on how to write nested query](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/184588/sharepoint-context-and-caml-query-is-not-working/184596)

Comment: Accept it as answer if solves the issue. it might helps others