# CAML Query Logics

Tags: caml

For this below logic, how to write a CAML query? Kindly guide me.

**Query Logic**:

where **department ='HR' And (Team='A' Or Team ='C' Or Team ='D')**

Here ***"department"*** and ***"Team"*** is column name and ***("HR","A","C","D")*** is value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Considered that `Team` and `Department` columns are text column.

```
"<Query><Where>"+
        "<And>"+
            "<Or>"+
                "<Or>"+
                     "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Team' /><Value Type='Text'>A</Value></Eq>"+
                     "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Team' /><Value Type='Text'>C</Value></Eq>"+
                "</Or>"+
                "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Team' /><Value Type='Text'>D</Value></Eq>"+
            "</Or>"+
            "<Eq><FieldRef Name='department' /><Value Type='Text'>HR</Value></Eq>"+
        "</And>"+               
    "</Where></Query>"
```

Check my answer on [how to write nested query](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/184588/sharepoint-context-and-caml-query-is-not-working/184596).

Comment: It is good to use free query builder tools, however if you understand the logic, it will be forever and you will not depend on any tools ever.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily create CAML queries if you use any of these s/w these are free to use and available in both install/offline packages. However, CAML query for your scenario would look like this.

> **Free CAML query builder:** [BIWUG CAML Designer](https://www.biwug.be/resources) for SP 2016/13/10 to O365

```
   <Where>
      <And>
         <Or>
            <Or>
               <Eq>
                  <FieldRef Name='Team/>
                  <Value Type='Choice'>A</Value>
               </Eq>
               <Eq>
                  <FieldRef Name='Team' />
                  <Value Type='Choice'>B</Value>
               </Eq>
            </Or>
            <Eq>
               <FieldRef Name='Team' />
               <Value Type='Choice'>C</Value>
            </Eq>
         </Or>
         <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='Department' />
            <Value Type='Choice'>HR</Value>
         </Eq>
      </And>
   </Where>
```

Comment: Your query logic is incorrect, you say **Department is 'HR' OR Team = 'A' OR Team = ...**. *Department* and any *Team* value should be in an *AND* clause.